# Задача с доской NxN на которой расположены слоны

Tags: python, c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

Есть доска для шахмат **NxN** клеток. На доску установили **M** шахматных слонов. Как известно, слон атакует по диагонали. Все клетки которые попадают под атаку назовем **"простреленными"**. Нужно найти те, которые не попадают под атаку слона.
Тех. условие.
Сначала вводим **N** *(1<=N<=1000000)* и **M** *(1<=M<=10000)* потом **M** пар чисел от 1 до **N** включительно - номер строки и столбца соответственно на которых находиться слон. Строки нумеруем снизу вверх а столбцы слева на право. Нумеруем строки и столбцы с единицы. Слоны не могут находиться на одной клетке. Программа выводит количество безопасных клеток.
Ввод:

```
10 6 4 7 8 5 8 7 6 2 9 7 8 4
```

Вывод:

```
33
```

[image: Пример для 6х6 доски]

Пожалуйста помогите, не могу понять как реализовать алгоритм + если можно то написать на с++ или питоне. Спасибо!

Comment: *"На доску установили **N** шахматных слонов."* Видимо, всё же **M**, а не **N**.

Comment: Отличная задача с неожиданным решением.

Answer (score 0):

Два булевских массива по номерам диагоналей. Для нового слона если диагональ ещё не использовалась, вычитаешь её длину. После этого заносишь в массив.

---

В описанном алгоритме ошибка: часть клеток вычитаются многократно, что к этому прибавить, я пока не понимаю.

Есть вариант при подсчёте слона вычитать из длин всех затрагиваемых диагоналей по 1, но это портит асимптотику и O(n+m) превращается в O(n*m), что не подходит под условия. Можно попробовать оптимизировать эту чать каким-нибудь деревом (Фенвика или отрезков), но я не думал в эту сторону, потому что почти наверняка должно быть линейное решение, а не такое.

Comment: Я пока в школе учусь, можно пожалуйста по подробней про массивы пожалуйста

Comment: @nod3ex Про массивы нужно в книжке читать. Или вам непонятно, как их тут применить?

Comment: Про дерево и апдейт на отрезке - скорее всего правильная идея. Если левая черная диагональ не использована, то она в зависимости от номера перекрывает определённый интервал правых черных диагоналей, и текущую сумму (количество имеющихся диагоналей) на этом интервале надо вычитать.

Comment: @MBo, без апдейта на отрезке - просто сумма с обновлением в точке. Кадлая перпендикулярная диагональ определяет границы [l, r], в которых она существует. Надо уметь по этим границам узнавать количество диагоналей между ними включительно. И так по 2 направлениям.

Comment: Пусть мы получили булевы массивы A и B. Тогда для каждой "пустой" диагонали A[i] мы хотим найти количество свободных клеток на ней. Чтобы это сделать найдем, какие диагонали из B пересекают A[i] - это будет отрезок [l; r]. Далее нужно просто подсчитать сумму B на отрезке [l; r] и вычислить количество свободных клеток на диагонали A[i], вычтя эту сумму из ее длины.

Comment: @EzikBro, да, я именно про это говорил в последнем комментарии.

Comment: Просто мне казалось, что вы продолжаете думать про дерево, но вам же никакие апдейты на самом деле не нужны. Нужно просто использовать префикс-суммы после подсчета массивов.

Comment: @EzikBro, да... Добавление перпендикулярной диагонали - это апдейт. У меня предполагается поштучное добавление слонов с подсчётом, сколько клеток сейчас бьётся. А ты как-то хочешь это в постобработку вынести? Сначала всё разметить, а потом посчитать? Я что-то пока не понял, как.

Comment: Да, сначала размещаем всех слонов. Тогда у нас есть два заполненных массива и мы идем по одному из них, а на втором считаем префикс-суммы. Тогда для каждой диагонали первого массива мы можем узнать номера перпендикулярных диагоналей, которые пересекают ее. Потом просто вычитаем из длины данной диагонали сумму на отрезке из второго массива.

Comment: Сейчас только порисовал и увидел, что там не непрерывный отрезок диагоналей, а они идут через одну - 6, 8, 10 для третьей диагонали на N=8. То есть нужно будет считать отдельные префикс-суммы для четных и нечетных диагоналей, но это не особо важно

Comment: @EzikBro, да, думаю так можно.

Answer (score 0):

По входным данным можно понять, что тут либо:

1. Алгоритм с параллельным просмотром разрядов за O(~nm),этот тот алгоритм, при котором мы используем битовые операции,даже при таких входных данных будет работать быстро не факт, что очень быстро
2. Формула

Скорее второе. Мы нумеруем диагонали в массиве, можно заметить что в каждой диагонали уменьшается кол-во клеток на 1. Но тут есть проблема, что слоны могут бить одну и ту же клетку, тогда формула работать не будет. А ответ, что привели выше работает как решето Эратосфена, O(~nm), а это слишком долго.
Поэтому либо надо знать какое ограничение по времени, либо придумывать умную формулу.

Кажется придумал умное решение:

Что же мы делаем, заводим для каждой диагонали сет(кч дерево работает за log(n)), после постановки слона мы удаляем все клетки, которые нам не нужны, которые он бьет, можно доказать что асимптотика не O(log(n)(n*m)),а O(log(n)(n+m)), потому что с каждым ходом слон точно вычёркивает один сет, а значит подсчет на каждом этапе будет уменьшаться

Еще одно умное решение:
Делаем ДО на диагоналях и просто на каждом этапе пересчитываем сумму, это делается ленивым за log(n), а в итоге сложность будет mlog(n), так как ДО с обновлением на отрезке будет работать за log(n)(ленивое обновление). ъ

Comment: Хм.. Описанный мной алгоритм работает за O(n+m), но он неверный - я проворонил, что часть клеток считается дважды. Надо ещё что-то прибавлять к ответу. (Ну или реально править под O(n*m), но это медленно.) Кстати, не понял, как в твоём ответе эта проблема решается.

Comment: А ну да, я думал ты в тупую делаешь, как в решете Эратосфена, но тут как я и говорил либо формула, что я и предложил, либо умное O(nm) с битами

Comment: Кажется, я могу повесить дерево отрезков с суммой диагоналей, тогда получится O(n*lb(n)), хотя тоже идею до конца не додумал. А с использованием битов у меня вообще нет идей. Ты предлагаешь эмулировать всё поле битами? (10**6)**2/8 = 125 GB памяти - не знаю, какие сейчас лимиты на одимпиадные задачки, но почти наверняка с таким - мимо.

Comment: сжатие координат

Comment: Хм.. Возможно, но там как-то сложно будет...

Answer (score 0):

Готовый код (Python):

```
size = int(input("Размер шахматной доски: "))
amount = int(input("Количество слонов: "))
print("")

def print_board(board):
    for lines in range(size):
        print(board[lines])
    print("")

board = []
board_2 = []
for row in range(size):
    board.append([])
    board_2.append([])
    for number in range(size):
        board[row].append(0)
        board_2[row].append(0)

f=0
while (f < amount):
    location_y = size - int(input("Введите строку слона: "))
    location_x = int(input("Введите столбец слона: ")) - 1
    board[location_y][location_x] = 1
    board_2[location_y][location_x] = 1
    f+=1

for row in range(size):
    for number in range(size):
        if (board[row][number] != 0):
            for n in range(1,size):
                if ((number+n <= size) and (row+n <= size)):
                    try:
                        board_2[row+n][number+n]=1
                    except:
                        None
                if ((number-n >= 0) and (row+n <= size)):
                    try:
                        board_2[row+n][number-n]=1
                    except:
                        None
                if ((number+n <= size) and (row-n >= 0)):
                    try:
                        board_2[row-n][number+n]=1
                    except:
                        None
                if ((number-n >= 0) and (row-n >= 0)):
                    try:
                        board_2[row-n][number-n]=1
                    except:
                        None
print_board(board_2)

zero=0
for row in range(size):
    zero = zero + board_2[row].count(0)

print(zero)

input()
```

При вызове `input()` показывается немного текста - подсказка к следующему действию.

Если подсказки не нужны, замените все конструкции `input(...)` на `input()`

Ограничения на размер поля, количество и расположение слонов думаю сможете добавить сами.

Comment: При size=миллион уже проверяли?

Comment: Какая сложность у вашего решения?

Comment: При size=1.000.000 время выполнения около 15 минут. Чтобы сократить время, можете добавить многопоточность в программу. Также можно переписать алгоритм на c++, т.к. python сам по себе не особо шустрый.

Сделал бы сам, но, честно говоря, уже голова не воспринимает эту задачу.

Comment: Какая сложность - не знаю, не разбираюсь в этом.

Comment: @nasiA чувак, чел просит решение с меткой алгоритм олимпиада, явно выполнение задачей контролируется системой, а значит ну хотя бы нужно знать асимптотику, хотя бы грубую(нет смысла считать потенциалами) А тут даже на вскидку O(n^2f(x)), которая явно не катает

Comment: Здесь вряд ли дадут готовое решение, я только предложил свой способ. Принять его или сделать по-своему - выбор автора.

Answer (score 0):

### Теория

Координаты клетки обозначим `(x, y), 1 <= x, y <= n`. Диагонали описываются уравнениями:

> ```
> x + y = s # s-диагональ (sum)
> x - y = d # d-диагональ (diff)
> ```

Самая длинная (длиной `n`) s-диагональ проходит через углы `(n, 1)` и `(1, n)`. Следовательно `s = n + 1`. Длина любой s-диагонали `n - |n + 1 - s|`.

Самая длинная (длиной `n`) d-диагональ проходит через углы `(1, 1)` и `(n, n)`. Следовательно `d = 0`. Длина любой d-диагонали `n - |d|`.

Лемма: пусть `s` и `d` одинаковой четности. s-диагональ пересекается с d-диагональю тогда и только тогда когда сумма их длин больше `n`.

### Практика

Составим множество чётных s-диагоналей занятых слонами. Аналогично построим множество чётных d-диагоналей. Слово "множество" означает что дубликаты диагоналей устранены.

Чтобы посчитать количество клеток покрытых чётными диагоналями нужно из суммы их длин вычесть количество попарных пересечений s- и d-диагоналей. Две конкретные диагонали пересекаются если сумма их длин больше `n`.

Конкретная s-диагональ пересекает все d-диагонали с длиной больше `|n + 1 - s|`. Если вектор (не множество) длин d-диагоналей отсортировать по убыванию, можно отыскать индекс (`i`) первой d-диагонали которая не пересекается с s-диагональю. Все диагонали до этого индекса пересекаются с s-диагональю.

Для ускорения процесса вектор длин s-диагоналей отсортируем по возрастанию длины. Тогда при увеличении длины s-диагонали индекс `i` не убывает.

Подсчёт занятых клеток займёт `O(mlogm)`, где `m` - число диагоналей (равно числу слонов в худшем случае). Это время займёт сортировка длин диагоналей. Дальнейший подсчёт пересечений делается за `O(m)`.

Нечётные s- и d-диагонали обрабатываются аналогично.

### Программа

```
def slen(n, s):
    return n - abs(n + 1 - s)


def dlen(n, d):
    return n - abs(d)


def attacked(n, sset, dset):
    slens = sorted( slen(n, s) for s in sset               )
    dlens = sorted((dlen(n, d) for d in dset), reverse=True)
    dlens.append(0) # sentinel

    sum_ = sum(slens) + sum(dlens)

    i = 0
    for sl in slens:
        while dlens[i] > n - sl:
            i += 1
        sum_ -= i
    return sum_


def available(n, poses):
    se = set()
    so = set()
    de = set()
    do = set()
    for x, y in poses:
        d = x - y
        s = x + y
        assert s % 2 == d % 2
        if s % 2 == 0:
            se.add(s)
            de.add(d)
        else:
            so.add(s)
            do.add(d)

    return n ** 2 - attacked(n, se, de) - attacked(n, so, do)


def main():
    n, m, *poses = map(int, input().split())
    it = iter(poses)
    print(available(n, zip(it, it)))


main()
```

**P.S.** Если `m` сравнимо с `n` или больше, то сортировку можно заменить на линейную (сортировку подсчетом) - длин диагоналей не более `n`. Итоговая сложность будет `O(min(n + m, mlogm))`.